# What is best way to install PHP 7.4 FPM on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu-18.04

I tried using below PPA repository below.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get install -y php7.4 php7.4-cli php7.4-json php7.4-common php7.4-mysql php7.4-zip php7.4-gd php7.4-mbstring php7.4-curl php7.4-xml php7.4-bcmath
```

I am getting these errors.

```
E: Unable to locate package php7.4-cli
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-cli'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-cli'
E: Unable to locate package php7.4-json
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.4-json'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.4-json'
```

I am easily able to install it on newer versions of Ubuntu.

I tried installing php7.4 and php7.4-fpm and I am getting errors. I might a fix or another alternative solution.

Comment: Compile it from the source, however, the effort that will be made in compiling php from source, you can use it on upgrading your source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please install **software-properties-common** first

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
```

After the above ,

then either execute

```
sudo apt-get install -y php7.4
```

or, if you wish

```
sudo apt-get install -y php7.4 php7.4-cli php7.4-json php7.4-common php7.4-mysql php7.4-zip php7.4-gd php7.4-mbstring php7.4-curl php7.4-xml php7.4-bcmath
```

**Additional Comments**

if your apt is out-of-date, please execute the following 2 lines first, before installing software-properties-common

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
```

If unfortunatley the binaries are removed (it happens) you may need to either (1) compile it (the old software version) by yourself, or (2) upgrade your OS distribution; or (3) use the archive . See [this post in Stack Exchange network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) and please also perform a web search such as `PHP Ondrej Archive` to find the archive resource you really need

One of the links will be

```
https://launchpad.net/~tomvlk/+archive/ubuntu/php-archive
```

Please note that it's not any kind of official repository so use it at the your own risk

Comment: I have done that. Same error.

Comment: likely that your apt is out-dated, please see additional comments above

Comment: I have performed an update and upgrade. same errors.

Comment: The binaries for unsupported Ubuntu versions have been removed from that repository, you check this online at https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php. Updating your apt won't make any difference to that. Installing from source is likely your only option @GyanendraGiri

Comment: Thanks Adyson for the comment. yes if unfortunatley the binaries are removed you may need to either (1) compile it (the old software version) by yourself, or (2) upgrade your OS distribution; or (3) use the archive --- see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: @KenLee Are you sure that includes 3rd-party PPAs such as the one we're discussing here?

Comment: You may google search `PHP Ondrej Archive` and see the result (but I did not try that's why I pointed some references to the OP on stackexchange)

Comment: You mean https://launchpad.net/~tomvlk/+archive/ubuntu/php-archive ? You should probably suggest that ppa in your answer then, instead of the one which doesn't work :-)

Comment: Thanks for your comments , I have done similar things in the past (posting external links which are not regarded as official documentations) and got reported as promoting spams (yes it happened).  
So... let me slightly revise my answer to incorporate this information.... Thank you again

Comment: I'd hope you'd be OK incorporating a Launchpad link. As long as you add the caveat that it's not any kind of official repository then it's at the reader's risk

Comment: @KenLee, by using https://launchpad.net/~tomvlk/+archive/ubuntu/php-archive PPA I am able to install php7.4.  php7.4-fpm and some other extensions are missing from this PPA too.

Comment: Yes the link may not store all the extensions archives (it is not official, as I have said), but the core modeules should be there. For example if you find that `php7.4-bcmath` is missing, then better try your luck to web search again for `php7.4-bcmath` and see whether you can still find other archive sites providing the required file